# How connect to multiple Redis servers, display combined results in optimized?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redis, booksleeve

If I have same multiple Redis servers. How connect to multiple database servers, obtain those hashes from each Redis server and then display the first 10 of the combined results ?

[image]

> For better understanding, I am using the site `StackOverflow` and other Q&A  as a case study. Of course, with my architecture.

**Central Company Server** offers a number of services to  **private company servers**. Each private servers within a `Q&A` website that (separately but with the same databases). There is information(Q&A) that the database private server-1, Owner of this information(Q&A), users are private server-1 (similarly to other servers).

Suppose that : PS1(Private Server-1) is `stackoverflow.com`, PS2 is `superuser.com`, PS3 `ham.stackexchange.com`, PS4 `android.stackexchange.com`, PS5 `anime.stackexchange.com`, PS6 is `askubuntu.com`.A user of a server, it opens one of these websites. Information taken from servers, and all this combined with the current server and the result is displayed. So all type of questions and answers will be displayed to the user.

> 1- Do I should be all the information to the **Central Company
>   Server** and then combined and send forward to **private company
>   servers** and users will display? get all data and then display the
>   first 10 of the combined results?
>
> 2- How without **Central Company Server** server do that?
>
> 3- What is the best way?
>
> 4- What is the optimal way?

Comment: Is this against a single db/key? If so, in master/slave we would expect the results from each to be (usually, not always) identical - so there is nothing to combine. Can you clarify the exact nature of the problem you want to solve?

Comment: Master server means (in my scenario) get all data from other server and combine , It's not master Redis , In my scenario, data is not concentrated in one place.Request a user from one server to another server and gathered.

Comment: I'm still unclear what you are after. If you want data from multiple servers: *ask multiple servers for data*...

Comment: Problem: If get data (1000000000000 and more hashes) from other servers and sort and then display the first 10 of the combined results,Is this the right way? What is the optimal way?(updated post better)

Comment: This is very much an architecture/design question - as such there is no "right" answer - it depends on too many variables. There isn't even a solid meaning of "optimal" here. Aggregating the data makes it more convenient, but uses more storage; querying in situ avoids storage, but is query-intensive, etc.

Comment: Hmmmm, Thanks @Marc Gravell.What do you think I should start?